# Rails 4 nested attributes not adding record to current project, instead it's adding new project records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

And the records from Project Updates are being uploaded to the new Project record.

I'm trying to use cocoon gem for nested attributes, but its adding new project record, and not just adding new project updates within the same project

I have the form in my **/views/projects/show.html.haml**

```
= form_for @pu do |f|
  #updates
    = f.simple_fields_for :project_updates do |u|
      = render 'update_fields', f: u
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'add updates', f, :project_updates, class: "button"
  = f.submit "Submit updates", class: "button"
```

Then in my **projects_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @pu = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :address, :client, :budget,
      project_updates_attributes: [:updates, :notes, :done, :impact_schedule, :impact_budget, :_destroy])
  end
```

I would like to continuously add records in the same project, if possible

EDIT, adding edit and update

```
def edit
end

def update

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Just standard edit and update scaffold.

Still having the issue of applying a nested attribute (form) inside a show page (project show page), and when trying to add new tasks in the project, it adds a new project record and includes the tasks in that new project, instead of updating the tasks in the current project. If its possible to help rewrite what I had, to fix, would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Per help, this is the result:

[image]
[image]

Status 1 was added (clicked on Submit updates), however, when I refresh the page, Status 1 input field shows up, and then when I tried to add another update (Status 2), the original Status 1 gets populated (in addition to the new updates), so there's going to be a continuous addition of previously added records. I just want this show page to only add new updates into the records, and not show existing records in input fields.

EDIT 2:

New form in show page, had to eliminate `url` per suggested answer below because it was giving me no route error

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  #updates
    = f.simple_fields_for :project_updates do |u|
      = render 'project_update_fields', f: u
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'add updates', f, :project_updates, class: "button"
  = f.submit "Submit updates", class: "button"
```

**_project_update_fields.haml** partial

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :updates, placeholder: "Updates", label: false
  .small-2.column
    = f.input :impact_budget, as: :boolean
  .small-2.column  
    = f.input :impact_schedule
  .small-12.column
    = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f, class: "button"
```

Comment: You are missing `edit` and `update` actions, or did you just omit to show them to us?

Comment: @nathanvda I updated my question, its just standard scaffolding actions

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues to work on.

First and the most important is here:

```
def show
  # instantiating new project_update is not even needed, nested_attributes will do that for you
  @pu = Project.new
end
```

To be able to update existing project, you need to do the following:

```
# change the show so that it finds the project which are at now:

def show
  # find a project we want to add updates to
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

# edit the form a bit
= form_for(@project, url: projects_path(@pu)) do |f| # <===, not nessecary though. Should work as you have it as well
  #updates
    = f.simple_fields_for :project_updates do |u|
      = render 'update_fields', f: u
```

## EDIT

To only create new updates (and not display existing ones on the project's edit form) you would do the following:

```
# making sure, that simple_fields_for are only displayed for new update object's creation
- if f.object.new_record?
  .nested-fields
    = f.input :updates, placeholder: "Updates", label: false
    .small-2.column
      = f.input :impact_budget, as: :boolean
    .small-2.column  
      = f.input :impact_schedule
    .small-12.column
      = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f, class: "button"
```

Comment: It now saves the records, but it also adds the previous records with new records that I'm trying to update. When I'm in the project show page, it shows the records in the input fields as if I'm editing the form. Does that make sense? How do i prevent this?

Comment: @hellomello `When I'm in the project show page, it shows the records in the input fields as if I'm editing the form.`, think of it - you are on the show page, it is logical that you are updating the existing record. Can I ask you to write what is your concern? Because I unfortunately do not understand it. I thought you wanted the form to be working and to add new `project_updates` to the existing project on the project page. You say it is working, so now I'd like to know what is there more to do, so I can hel you further :)

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for the help. I've updated my OP to screenshot my issues. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: @hellomello it is very simple, it is a matter of the partial's code. Please, post the partial and I will show you, how to only add new updates :)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my OP. But you'll see that I had to modify a little bit of the form you suggested.

Comment: @hellomello hey, no problem, glad it worked as you expected :) So i assume you accept my answer? ooo, ok, I didn't notice you've granted bounty :D

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to split your actions into create and update. That way you can update an existing record.

Your update action will be very similar, but instead of

```
@project = Project.new(...)
```

It will be something like

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
```

Also, you will want to call `@project.update_attributes(project_params)` instead of `@project.save`
Good luck. If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: How come I want to change `Project.new(..)` to `Project.find(params[:project_id])`? I'm trying to create a nested attribute to an existing project show page where users can update project status within the project. Also, the `@project.save` in the create action is for when I create a new project, no?

Comment: Sure, but you also want to update things, right? For that you need a new action named `update`, and in that action you should replace the methods as I have stated. There is nothing wrong with the code you wrote, but it just creates new projects every time. If you want to update a project, you need a new action with the instructions I gave you. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What about `@pu = Project.new`? Because this form that's in the show page, is to `action="/projects"`. Maybe I need to change this? Because if I change the original scaffold items, it would affect when I create new projects, right?

Comment: The page in new should be a post to /projects. You should also have an `edit` action, with an edit view, with a form PATCH to /projects. In rails, that's the same as saying edit_project_path(PROJECT_ID)

Comment: So I guess that's my issue here. I'm not trying to post a new project, i'm only trying to add new tasks within the project. I'm in the show page of the project, and there's a form that only adds updates. If its to `/projects` doesn't that create a new project, not the "project update" (lets call tasks)? Sorry for my n00b questions, I'm trying to understand and hopefully get this working. Maybe I've been confusing you between updates and tasks